# can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes while subtracting date with offset mentioned

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

My basic requirement is I have a datetime string `dt_a_str` and I have to calculate the difference between it and current datetime. However, with my current code i get following error:

```
Python 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> dt_a_str = '2022-04-16T14:27:47.1069564Z'
>>> dt_a = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_a_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f4Z")
>>> dt_b = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> diff = abs((dt_b - dt_a).seconds)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

As per my understanding I am converting time along with offset that is `.%f4Z"` but why it still saying that is it as a offset-naive date.

Comment: a literal 'Z' is probably not what you want if you want to parse the Z from the input to an aware datetime object (UTC). Try using %z instead; `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f4%z"`. Using a literal Z just ignores the UTC identifier in the input. Btw. dateutil's parser could handle 7 digits of fractional digits; see [isoparse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse).

Comment: @FObersteiner adding `%z` gives `raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" % ValueError: time data '2022-05-16T14:27:47.1069564Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'`

Comment: this is because you have 7 digits of fractional seconds; %f only parses 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only compare datetime objects that are either both naive (no tzinfo) or both aware (tzinfo set). Using a literal Z in the parsing directive does not parse Z to UTC. It just makes the parser ignore it, like you could do with any character (such as ':' for instance).

With **Python 3.11**, [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) handles 7 digits of fractional seconds ***and*** parse the  `Z` to UTC:

```py
Python 3.11.3 (main, May  3 2023, 11:09:17) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

from datetime import datetime
dt_a_str = '2022-04-16T14:27:47.1069564Z'

print(datetime.fromisoformat(dt_a_str))
2022-04-16 14:27:47.106956+00:00
```

---

`formisoformat` was upgraded in 3.11, so for older Python versions, a third party parser is probably the safer option. E.g.

```py
from dateutil.parser import isoparse
dt_a_str = '2022-04-16T14:27:47.1069564Z'

print(isoparse(dt_a_str))
2022-04-16 14:27:47.106956+00:00
```

or

```py
from iso8601 import parse_date
dt_a_str = '2022-04-16T14:27:47.1069564Z'

print(parse_date(dt_a_str))
2022-04-16 14:27:47.106956+00:00
```